# Regexp exact word match

Tags: regex, printf, match

I need to match words from lines. For example:

```
The blue bird is dancing.
Yellow card is drawn
The day is perfect rainy
blue bird is eating
```

The four lines are in a text file `l2`.

I want to match the blue bird, yellow card, day and every time a line is printed that matched word is printed before the line.

```
y=regexp(l2,('^(?=.*blue bird)|(?=.*day)|(?=.*Yellow card)$'));
```

Is this how it works? I can't get the result.

```
sprintf('[%s]',y,l2);
```

Comment: What language do you use?

Comment: MATLAB
can we use (\bYellow card\b)|(\bday\b) in MATLAB i think that \b..\b can extract out exact word match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MATLAB's regex engine doesn't use `\b` as word boundary anchors [but `\<` and `\>`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/matlab_prog/regular-expressions.html#f0-42983).

So your regex would become

```
y = regexp(l2, '^(?=.*\<(?:blue bird|day|Yellow card)\>).*', 'lineanchors');
```

assuming that `l2` is a multiline string.

Comment: if I choose to print it , it give me following error
sprintf('[%s][%s]',y,l2)

Warning: The argument for the %s format specifier
must be of type char (a string).

Comment: `regexp` returns an array with the starting positions of the matches. Did you read the documentation I linked to? If you want the matches to be returned, you need the `'match'` option. But you'll still have an array, not a single string, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Try this reg exp.

```
(?:blue bird|yellow card|day)
```