# Searching in a textfile words with specific endings in MATLAB

Tags: regex, matlab

I have the following textfile (MATLAB):

```
myText = 'In a starry night, the czar and the star drove the car to a bar not far away: ar, ar.'
```

Now I have the task to extract all words ending with "ar". I've tried it with the following code, but I have the problem that I do not account for 2-letter words (such as the "ar" "ar" at the end of the phrase).

```
regexp(myText,'[a-z]+ar[^a-z]','match')
```

Does anyone have a way to include the two letter words aswell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern you tried `[a-z]+ar[^a-z]` expects at least 4 characters:

- `[a-z]+` matches 1 or more times a-z
- `ar` 2 characters
- `[^a-z]` negated character class, matches any char except a-z

One option to also match the 2 letter words `ar` in the example string is to repeat the character class 0+ times `[a-z]*`

Then match `ar` and use [word boundaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25306738/regexp-exact-word-match) `\<` and `\>`

```
\<[a-z]*ar\>
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dyWeno/1)

Answer (score 1):

How about this one

```
([a-z]+|)ar[^a-z]
```